# Creating a table in HTML using data from MySQL Database not working

Tags: php, mysql, html, apache

I am trying to display a table on a webpage from MySQL database, but it's now working! Here's my code:

```
<?php 
    function list_schools() {
       $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "Database_Project");
       if ($conn === false) {
          die("Could not connect:"  . mysqli_connect_error()); 
       } 

       $output = "";
       $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT school_id, name, address, phone_number, email, type FROM Schools;") or die('cannot show tables');       
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
          $output .= '
          <tr>
          <td>' . $row['school_id'] . '</td>
          <td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>                                                   
          <td>' . $row['address'] . '</td>
          <td>' . $row['phone_number'] . '</td>
          <td>' . $row['email'] . '</td> 
          <td>' . $row['type'] . '</td>                                    
          </tr>';
       }
       return $output;

    }

    $exec_func = list_schools();
?>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="sortable">
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Phone Number</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <?php echo exec_func; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Whenever I try displaying it on my browser I get the following:

1

cannot show columns from 1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're selecting `school_id`, not `ID`

Comment: I corrected that, but still, no table is showing @aynber

Comment: Also, what is `exec_func`? You're missing the dollar sign if you're trying to echo the return variable.

Comment: @aynber no I'm afraid that's not the case; still not working

Comment: Are you still getting "cannot show columns from 1", or another message? What is showing on the screen now?

Comment: @aynber yes it's the same exact message "cannot show columns from 1". any idea what might be causing the problem?

Comment: That's coming from your code somewhere, it's not a generic error message. Can you show the code where that message shows up?

Comment: @aynber apparently I had tried another code earlier for making a table that's what's been causing the problem

Comment: @aynber but thank you so much Aynber. I'll delete the question in  a minute. Just wanted to thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

From your query, it's pretty obvious that you'll not get `ID` column, but `school_id`.

So merely correct your statement when building `$output`:

```
     <td>' . $row['school_id'] . '</td>
```

Comment: @thelili018 But this effectively solved the issue you showed in your OP. Now it's a different question!

Answer (score 0):

Why not try:

```
<?php 
    function list_schools() {
       $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "Database_Project");
       if ($conn === false) {
          die("Could not connect:"  . mysqli_connect_error()); 
       } 

       $output = "";
       $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT school_id, name, address, phone_number, email, type FROM Schools;") or die('cannot show tables');       



    }

    $exec_func = list_schools();
?>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="sortable">
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Phone Number</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
          echo '
          <tr>
          <td>' . $row['school_id'] . '</td>
          <td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>                                                   
          <td>' . $row['address'] . '</td>
          <td>' . $row['phone_number'] . '</td>
          <td>' . $row['email'] . '</td> 
          <td>' . $row['type'] . '</td>                                    
          </tr>'; } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this following code

```
   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="sortable">
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Phone Number</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
   <?php 
       $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "Database_Project");
       if ($conn === false) {
          die("Could not connect:"  . mysqli_connect_error()); 
       } 

        $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT school_id, name, address, phone_number, email, type FROM Schools");
        while($obj = $results->fetch_object()) { 
         ?>
          <tr>
          <td> <?php echo $row['school_id']; ?> </td>
          <td> <?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>                                                   
          <td> <?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
          <td> <?php echo $row['phone_number']; ?></td>
          <td> <?php echo $row['email']; ?></td> 
          <td><?php echo $row['type']; ?></td>                                    
          </tr>
      <?php
       }
?>


    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT school_id, name, address, phone_number, email, type FROM Schools;") or die('cannot show tables');
```

you cannot use `or` operator here.
Check this [Logical Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) for explanation.

example:

```
echo 't' or 'f'; //will output 1
```

use this code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT school_id, name, address, phone_number, email, type FROM Schools;")
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if (!$num_rows) {
die('cannot show tables');   
}
```